# Calcular todos los números primos raros hasta un número dado en Java

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente enunciado y no entiendo muy bien que es lo que pide:

> Decimos que un numero `n` es raro cuando verifica que para cualquier número `m <= n` y tal que ambos son primos entre sí, resulte que `m` es primo (dos números son primos entre sí cuando el máximo común divisor de ambos números es la unidad). Escribe un programa que liste todos los números raros entre 3 y un valor introducido por el usuario.

El código que tengo hasta el momento es este:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EjercicioPrimos {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Introduzca un número para calcular los primos:");
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = teclado.nextInt();
    boolean primos;
    for (int m = 3; m < n; m++) {
        primos = mcd(n, m);
        if (primos == true) {
            System.out.println(n + " " + m + " Son primos entre si.");
        } else if (primos == false) {
            System.out.println(n + " " + m + " No son primos entre si.");
        }
    }
}

public static boolean mcd(int n, int m) {
    boolean primos = true;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0 && m % i == 0) { 
            primos = false;
        }
    }
    return primos;
  }
}
```

Y la salida para el numero 25 por consola me calcula solo si el número introducido es primo. Sin embargo, no me lo calcula en todo el intervalo de números [1,25]:

```
25 3 Son primos entre si.
25 4 Son primos entre si.
25 5 No son primos entre si.
25 6 Son primos entre si.
25 7 Son primos entre si.
25 8 Son primos entre si.
25 9 Son primos entre si.
25 10 No son primos entre si.
25 11 Son primos entre si.
25 12 Son primos entre si.
25 13 Son primos entre si.
25 14 Son primos entre si.
25 15 No son primos entre si.
25 16 Son primos entre si.
25 17 Son primos entre si.
25 18 Son primos entre si.
25 19 Son primos entre si.
25 20 No son primos entre si.
25 21 Son primos entre si.
25 22 Son primos entre si.
25 23 Son primos entre si.
25 24 Son primos entre si.
```

Comment: @Fernando viendo el código lo entiendo mucho mejor que leyendo el enunciado. Quizás te pueda ayudar con qué tipo de preguntas se hacen en [es.so]. Creo que podrías cambiarlo a algo como: "*En la variable `n` tengo un entero introducido por el usuario. Estoy intentando hacer un bucle con `m = 3` hasta `n` que me liste todos los números que cumplan `mcd(m,n) == 1`... Intenté esto: `<tu código>`, pero estoy teniendo problemas con `<el problema>` porque en `<algún caso>` no devuelve `<valor esperado>`*".... Algo así se espera en una pregunta... Y algo así tendría respuestas.

Comment: @Fernando entonces volvemos a lo que te comenté antes: si tu problema es no entender el enunciado, este no es el sitio para preguntar. Por otro lado, si en algún otro momento entendés cuál es el objetivo y no estás pudiendo lograrlo por algo específico en el código, más que bienvenido a hacer una nueva pregunta... Lo lamento, pero es parte de lo que garantiza que en [es.so] haya buenas preguntas, concretas, y de programación... Personalmente, te recomendaría no perder tiempo acá y preguntarle a tu profesor lo que no entendiste.

Comment: @FernandoBenavidel de la forma que estás preguntando, la pregunta probablemente siga cerrada. Lo que se espera de una pregunta en el sitio es que aclares **un problema específico** que estás teniendo con el código, reduciendo el código a lo mínimo para poder reproducirlo, tal cual se explica en [mcve]. Una pregunta que dice "este es mi código, cómo se puede mejorar" no es sobre un problema puntual, y por ende no tendría una única respuesta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Después de la explicación de @user3927886 que proponia una solucion con Haskell, primos entre sí no significa que sean números primos (el 9 y el 10 son primos entre sí pero ninguno de los dos es primo - y te lo pone en el propio enunciado, mcd(n,m) = 1).

-Un ejemplo para el valor introducido 5 y verifiquemos si 5 es raro. Para verificar esto, debemos pasar por todos los enteros del 1 al 5. Si alguno de ellos es un primo de 5, pero NO es primo, entonces 5 no es raro. De lo contrario, 5 es raro (según la definición de raro). Hagamoslo:

`i = 1`: ¿1 es un primo de 5? Sí lo es, porque el único divisor común es 1. ¿Es 1 primo? Sí. De acuerdo. Continuamos con i = 2.

`i = 2`: ¿Es 2 un primo de 5? Sí lo es, porque el único divisor común es 1. ¿Es 2 primo? Sí OK. Continuar.

`i = 3`: ¿3 es un primo de 5? Sí, lo es, porque el único divisor común es 1. ¿Es 3 primo? Sí OK. Continuar.

`i = 4`: ¿4 es un primo de 5? Sí, lo es, porque el único divisor común es 1. ¿Es 4 primo? ¡NO!

Así que hemos encontrado un número i <5 que es un primo de 5 pero no primo normal. Entonces 5 no es raro y es por eso que 5 no es parte de la salida del programa.

La solución con código del problema en Java seria

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pruebas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        long n;
        do{
            System.out.println("Introduce un numero para calcular los numeros raros entre 3 y ese numero, ambos inclusive:");
        n= teclado.nextLong();
        if(n<=2){
            System.out.println("Introduce un numero de nuevo valido");
        }
        }while(n<=2);

        for (long m = 3; m < n; m++) {
            boolean raro = true;
            for (long i = 2; i <= m; i++) {

                if (mcd(i, m) && !numeroPrimos(i)) {
                    raro = false;
                }
            }

            if (raro) {
                System.out.print(m + ",");
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean mcd(long n, long m) {
        boolean primos = true;
        for (long i = 2; i <= n && i <= m; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0 && m % i == 0) {
                primos = false;
            }
        }
        return primos;
    }

    public static boolean numeroPrimos(long n) {
        boolean primo = true;
        for (long i = 2; i < n; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                primo = false;
            }
        }
        return primo;
    }

}
```

SALIDA: La única solución para el mayor número representable de tipo long seria la secuencia `3,4,6,8,12,18,24,30`

Answer (score 3):

"No entender el enunciado" no parece un problema de programación.

Aún así, creo que está bien explicado. Primos entre sí no significa que sean números primos (el 9 y el 10 son primos entre sí pero ninguno de los dos es primo - y te lo pone en el propio enunciado, mcd(n,m) = 1).

Supongo que a falta de otra opción mejor:

Dado un input n del usuario, haz un bucle hasta n, que en cada paso compruebe si el número correspondiente es raro; esto es, otro bucle de 1 al paso en el que estas que te informe de los numeros primos con dicho paso, y que compruebe si son primos.

Edit: solución en Haskell:

```
import Data.Numbers.Primes (isPrime)

listarNumerosRaros :: Int -> [Int]
listarNumerosRaros n = [x | x <- [3..n] , esRaro x]


esRaro :: Int -> Bool
esRaro x = isPrime `all` [y | y <- [1..x] , gcd x y == 1]
```

y el resultado en la terminal:

```
*Main> listarNumerosRaros 100000
[]
```

osea que por lo visto sí que son muy raros jeje

Edit2: resulta que `isPrime 1` devuelve False, por lo que mi código de arriba está mal. Así sí:

```
import Data.Numbers.Primes (isPrime)

listarNumerosRaros :: Int -> [Int]
listarNumerosRaros n = [x | x <- [3..n] , esRaro x]


esRaro :: Int -> Bool
esRaro x = isPrime `all` [y | y <- [2..x] , gcd x y == 1]
```

y el resultado en la terminal:

```
*Main Data.Numbers.Primes> listarNumerosRaros 300000
[3,4,6,8,12,18,24,30]
```

Comment: Parece que no funciona correctamente. En los resultados que pones, los números raros de 3 a 300000 no pueden ser 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 18, 24 y 30, porque por ejemplo, 4 y 300000 comparten un divisor común: 2.

Comment: 1. La versión retocada de mi código funciona perfectamente (creo)

Comment: 2. Leer java me da cáncer de ojo, pero lo intentaré:

  - Siempre puedes evitar hacer `if (primos == true)` haciendo simplemente `if primos`

  - Como has puesto que `primos = mcd(n,m)`, creo que deberías hacer `if primos == 1` y quitar el if despues del else

  - Leyendo la segunda función, creo que en vez de mcd deberías llamarla `sonCoprimos` ya que realmente no estás calculando el máximo común divisor (que debería devolver un entero y no un booleano) - también puedes hacer el bucle hasta el mínimo de n y m.

Comment: 3. No es la solución porque te pide encontrar los números raros desde 3 hasta el input del usuario, y tú estás devolviendo los coprimos con n desde 3 hasta n (siendo n el input del usuario)

Comment: De momento he leído las 2 últimas funciones y están bien, pero a `numeroPrimos` la llamaría `esPrimo` y a `mcd` la llamaría `sonCoprimos`. De la primera función solamente he leído el nombre, pero "cousins" me ha hecho gracia (número primo es prime number en inglés ^^')

Comment: Parece que tu solución funciona perfectamente (el boolean cousins no lo utilizas, y el while supongo que es para evitar que el usuario introduzca un número menor que 3, aunque está debajo - si funciona pues perfecto, no estoy acostumbrado a ver los while debajo de lo que quieres repetir). Ah y no entiendo tu comentario de (2^63-1).

Comment: Para optimizar los tiempos de ejecución deberías parar los bucles en cuanto encuentras las condiciones que cambian los `true` a `false`

Comment: No lo he ejecutado (no tengo java instalado) pero estoy bastante seguro de que funciona exactamente como debería (bueno en el caso extremo de que el usuario introduzca el valor 2 no se qué pasará). Enhorabuena y gracias por aceptar mi respuesta (si le das un +1 ya te lo marcas)